Call to a member function attach() on null in laravel
i have many to many relation in my project tasks and offices table :
task model:
public function offices(): BelongsToMany 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Office::class)->withPivot('main_office'); 
    }

office model:
public function tasks(): BelongsToMany    
    {       
        return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class)->withPivot('main_office');
    }

in store function in controller:
public function store(taskRequestStore $request,TaskService $service)
    {
        $offices=Office::where([['top_office_id',null],['status',1]])->get();
        $attributes = $request->all(['Caption','TaskDsc','TaskDate','Priority_id',
                                'Type','TaskFile','FilePath','StartDate','EndDate','Deadline',
                                'Commander_id','Status_id'
                                ]);
        $tasks = $service->create($attributes);
        // dd($tasks,$offices);
        $tasks->$offices->attach([1]);
       return redirect()->back();
    }

The record is inserted in the tasks table, but an error is issued for the attach command.
when active dd :

Where is the error in my code?

$tasks->$offices should probably be $tasks->offices.

Your issue is this line:
$tasks->$offices->attach([1]);

It should be:
$tasks->offices()->attach($offices);

Because you want to attach the offices to the tasks, you have to call the relationship (offices() instead of offices) and pass what you want to attach.
If using attach($offices) does not work, use ->attach($offices->pluck('id')->toArray()).
Still, your issue is that $offices is null, so you are not getting data back when you run ->get(), so it will never attach anything

Correction from @Tim Lewis:

$tasks->$offices is valid syntax (i.e. if you had something like $offices = 'offices';), but it would try to convert that Collection to a String, and then do $tasks->{whatever a Collection to String is}, which definitely is null. The main issues are $tasks->$offices vs $task->offices() (the $ and missing ())


"Still, your issue is that $offices is null" - Not quite. $offices is the result of ->get(), so it would be a Collection (empty or otherwise), not null. $tasks->$offices is valid syntax (i.e. if you had something like $offices = 'offices';), but it would try to convert that Collection to a String, and then do $tasks->{whatever a Collection to String is}, which definitely is null. The main issues are $tasks->$offices vs $task->offices() (the $ and missing ())

Screenshot to hopefully clarify what I'm talking about: https://i.sstatic.net/4aEZCSsL.png

@TimLewis totally true! I realized later, let me update it

Cheers! I'd upvote again if I could, but y'know
